# Dynamic multi-level drop down using MySQL DB

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to create a multi level drop down menu hopefully using PHP since I have no prior experience in javascript but I am willing to learn that also. To make this easy for everyone to understand I am using cars as and example. I want the user to select a "Brand" example Ford, then a second drop down will populate with the "Models" Ford has made and finally a third drop down will populate with "Colors" of Ford vehicles. I am using a MySQL database that I want to pull all of the data from dynamically instead of hardcoding the values in. I am able to get the first drop down to populate with the "Brands" but when I select a "Brand" the second drop down does not populate with the new results. I am new to PHP and MySQL but a very quick learner. Here is my code:

INSERT_DROPDOWN.PHP

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","XXXXXXXXXX");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

// Write out BRANDS.
$dquery = "SELECT brand FROM manufacture ORDER BY brand";
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$dresult = mysql_query($dquery) or die(mysql_error());

// Write out MODELS.
$dquery1 = "SELECT 'brand', 'model' FROM models WHERE brand='$dresult' ORDER BY model";
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$dresult1 = mysql_query($dquery1) or die(mysql_error());


// Write out COLORS.
$dquery2 = "SELECT color FROM color ORDER BY color";
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$dresult2 = mysql_query($dquery2) or die(mysql_error());

// if successful insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($dresult){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR />";
}

else {
echo "ERROR1";
}

// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

TESTING.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <LINK href="CLL.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title> 
           testing
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php 
require "insert_dropdown.php";
?>

<p>
  <?php
    //Brand
    $dropdown = "<select name='brand'>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dresult)) 
    {

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['brand']}'>{$row['brand']}</option>";

    }

    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown;

    //Model
        $dropdown1 = "<select name='brand'>";
      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dresult1)) 
    {

    $dropdown1 .= "\r\n<option value='{$row1['model']}'>{$row['brand']}</option>";

    }

    $dropdown1 .= "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown1;

    //Color
        $dropdown = "<select name='name'>";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dresult2)) 
    {

    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['color']}'>{$row['color']}</option>";

    }

    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown;
  ?>
</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know you said you're a beginner, but how do you expect things to happen if you don't actually use code? You said you want the second dropdown to be populated based on the first dropdown...but you aren't using any kind of action for "onchange" to do what you want - the browser doesn't magically know that you want this to happen. Your code seems to make 3 queries to the database, and populate 3 `<select>` elements on the page...that's it. What you're looking for is something like AJAX, or better storing of information from your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code by using AJAX