# How to create Multilevel drop down list using html,php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am new to this,so can one give reference to create multilevel drop down list.
As explain belove. 
for example,
I have to create two dropdown list one is category and another is sub category.
When i am select one field in category then sub categoey will give me only those field which is sub part of category..
if i am select category1 then
category-1----->in subcategory dropdown sub1,sub2 are display
category-2----->sub3,sub4,sub5
like wise....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic multi-level drop down using MySQL DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111821/dynamic-multi-level-drop-down-using-mysql-db)

Comment: Please paste your tried code :)

Comment: Refer [bootstrap multi-level dropdown](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) or [pure css multi-level dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100344/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu)

Comment: i am not try any thing i want some reference so i can start to code

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution.

```
// HTML
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">A ></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">A1 ></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">A1A ></a>
                      <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">A1A1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">A1A2</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                 <li><a href="#">A1B</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
         <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>

// CSS
ul li > ul{
    display:none;
}

ul li:hover >ul{
    display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ok75y06z/1/)

Comment: i can use anything either php or java script or jquery or AJAX. In what ever  it is possible just give me reference for that.